# Sample and group by, and pivot time series data

Tags: pandas, time-series

I'm struggling to handle a complex (imho) operation on time series data.

I have a time series data set and would like to break it into nonoverlapping pivoted grouped by chunks. It is organized by customer, year, and value. For the purposes of this toy example, I am trying to break it out into a simple forecast of the next 3 months.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'a',  5: 'a', 6: 'a', 7: 'b', 8: 'b', 9: 'b'},
                   'Year': {0: 2020, 1: 2020, 2: 2020, 3: 2020, 4: 2020,  5: 2021, 6: 2021, 7: 2020,  8: 2020, 9: 2020},
                   'Month': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10, 3: 11, 4: 12,  5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 3},
                   'Value': {0: 5.2, 1: 2.2, 2: 1.7, 3: 9.0, 4: 5.5,  5: 2.5, 6: 1.9, 7: 4.5, 8: 2.9, 9: 3.1}})
```

My goal is to create a dataframe where each row contains non overlapping data that is in 3 month pivoted increments. So each row has the 3 "value" data points upcoming from that point in time. I'd also like this data to include the most recent data, so if there is an odd amount of data, that data is dropped (see example a).

```
| Customer | Year | Month | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 |
|     b    | 2020 |   1   |   4.5  |   2.9  |  3.1   |
|     a    | 2020 |   9   |   2.2  |   1.7  |  9.0   |
|     a    | 2020 |  12   |   5.5  |   2.5  |  1.9   |
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: In case you have 6 or more dates for 1 customer, would you like to have 2 or more rows for this customer or only 1 ?

Comment: just 2. i updated the example for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to first `sort_values` on your df so latest month goes first, assign group numbers and drop those not in groups of 3:

```
df = df.sort_values(["Year", "Month", "Customer"], ascending=False)
df["group"] = (df.groupby("Customer").cumcount()%3).eq(0).cumsum()
df = df[(df.groupby(["Customer", "group"])["Year"].transform("size").eq(3))]
df["num"] = (df.groupby("Customer").cumcount()%3+1).replace({1:3, 3:1})

print (df)

  Customer  Year  Month  Value  group  num
6        a  2021      2    1.9      2    3
5        a  2021      1    2.5      2    2
4        a  2020     12    5.5      2    1
3        a  2020     11    9.0      3    3
2        a  2020     10    1.7      3    2
1        a  2020      9    2.2      3    1
9        b  2020      3    3.1      5    3
8        b  2020      2    2.9      5    2
7        b  2020      1    4.5      5    1
```

Now you can pivot your data:

```
print (df.assign(Month=df["Month"].where(df["num"].eq(1)).bfill(),
                 Year=df["Year"].where(df["num"].eq(1)).bfill(),
                 num="Month"+df["num"].astype(str))
         .pivot(["Customer","Month","Year"], "num", "Value")
         .reset_index())

num Customer  Month    Year  Month1  Month2  Month3
0          a    9.0  2020.0     2.2     1.7     9.0
1          a   12.0  2020.0     5.5     2.5     1.9
2          b    1.0  2020.0     4.5     2.9     3.1
```

Comment: I think you need customer at the front of the index. otherwise looks good and works!

Comment: your pivot should actually be pivot_table i believe. i need to change that in order for it to work. make the edits and i'm happy to award the answer.

Comment: `pivot_table` aggregates your data (`np.mean` by default). If it didnt work using `pivot`, there must be duplicates in your data set.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way to do this, but this will give you the output you want :

First we add a `Customer_counter` column to add an ID to rows member of the same chunk, and we remove extra rows.

```
df["Customer_chunk"] = (df[::-1].groupby("Customer").cumcount()) // 3
df = df.groupby(["Customer", "Customer_chunk"]).filter(lambda group: len(group) == 3)
```

Then we group by Customer and Customer_chunk to generate each column of the desired output.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["Customer", "Customer_chunk"])
colYear = df_grouped["Year"].first()
colMonth = df_grouped["Month"].first()
colMonth1 = df_grouped["Value"].first()
colMonth2 = df_grouped["Value"].nth(2)
colMonth3 = df_grouped["Value"].last()
```

And finally we create the output by merging every columns.

```
df_output = pd.concat([colYear, colMonth, colMonth1, colMonth2, colMonth3], axis=1).reset_index().drop("Customer_chunk", axis=1)
```

Some steps feel a bit clunky, there's probably room for improvement in this code but it shouldn't impact performance too much.